# How to check if the result of division is int or float

Tags: android, math, int, operators

I was making 2 generated integers and then I divided them. I want to check the result of 2 divided integers are an integer or decimal. Then I will try to compare the result and integered the result with a string with this code but its stops working.

```
Random r = new Random();
int first = r.nextInt(50 - 1) + 1;

Random z = new Random();
int twond = z.nextInt(50 - 1) + 1;

float Resultas = (first / twond);
Result = (int) Resultas;
String floatResult = Float.toString(Resultas);

while (floatResult != String.valueOf(Result)) {
  Random s = new Random();
  first = s.nextInt(50 - 1) + 1;

  Random y = new Random();
  twond = y.nextInt(50 - 1) + 1;

  Resultas = (first / twond);
  Result = (int) Resultas;
  floatResult = Float.toString(Resultas);
}
```

Comment: use [TypeVariable](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/reflect/TypeVariable.html)..

Comment: Why stops the code working. Gives it an exception and can you add this to your question? Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: H. Pauwelyn I dont understand what you talking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (first % twond == 0) {
    // result is an integer
}
```

Comment: i was trying : while (first % twond != 0) { } because i want to regenerate the first and twond to get Integer result. But its still not working.

Comment: @Fachri ...why don't you make it easier and just generate an integer, then multiple it by another generated integer?

Comment: Karakuri@ i want to make a math quiz where I need the first int and twond int.